# Odd usage of special pointer values

Tags: c++, pointers

I am using a C++ implementation of an algorithm which makes odd usage of special pointer values, and I would like to known how safe and portable is this.

First, there is some structure containing a pointer field. It initializes an array of such structures by zeroing the array with `memset()`. Later on, the code relies on the pointer fields initialized that way to compare equal to `NULL`; wouldn't that fail on a machine whose internal representation of the `NULL` pointer is not all-bits-zero?

Subsequently, the code sets some pointers to, and laters compares some pointers being equal to, specific pointer values, namely `((type*) 1)` and `((type*) 2)`. Clearly, these pointers are meant to be some flags, not supposed to be dereferenced. But can I be sure that some genuine valid pointer would not compare equal to one of these? Is there any better (safe, portable) way to do that (i.e. use specific pointer values that can be taken by pointer variables only through explicit assignment, in order to flag specific situations)?

Any comment is welcome.

Comment: Description of code is almost always less effective than example of code. That said it looks like you are going very low-level. Any reason to do this instead of using constructors and keeping things typesafe?

Comment: a common technique is to create a sentinal object and point unused pointers to it. then the comparison becomes the address of the sentinal object means unused pointer.

Comment: "*wouldn't that fail on a machine whose internal representation of the NULL pointer is not all-bits-zero?*" - yes. "*can I be sure that some genuine valid pointer would not compare equal to one of these?*" - typically, most OSes reserve such low memory addresses for their own private use. Also, certain ways of allocating memory tend to align addresses in such a way that leaves a few bits available in pointers, which are commonly exploited for [tagged pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer). So yes, such low memory addresses generally do not appear in application memory

Comment: If someone do that, then the code is not intended to be portable. As far as the language is concerned, I believe, it is undefined behavior. In practice, it probably works as expected on most system.

Comment: @user4581301 I guess such low-level tricks are there for performance reasons, or maybe the programmer just was lazy (it is research code, not supposed to be deployed as is). Since I am lazy as well I might just do the few changes needed to ensure portability and not write proper constructors.
@dgsomerton Do you mean something like `static const type reserved;` and `static const type* sentinel = &reserved;`?
@RemyLebeau It is precisely the ".../generally/ do not appear..." which bothers me, I wish for more guarantees, if there is an easy way to get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up the comments I received, both issues raised in the question are indeed expected to work on "usual" setup, but comes with no guarantee.

Now if I want absolute guarantees, it seems my best option is, for the `NULL` pointers, set them either manually or with a proper constructor, and for the special pointer values, to create manually *sentinel* pointer values.

For the latter, in a C++ class I guess the most elegant solution is to use static members

```
class The_class
{
    static const type reserved;
    static const type* const sentinel;
};
```

provided that they can be initialized somewhere:

```
const type The_class::reserved = foo; // 'foo' is a constant expression of type 'type'
const type* const The_class::sentinel = &The_class::reserved;
```

If `type` is templated, either the above initialization must be instantiated for each `type` intended, or one must resort to non-`static` (less elegant but still usefull) "reserved" and "sentinel" members.

```
template <typename type>
class The_class
{
    type reserved; // cannot be static anymore, nor const for complicated 'type' without adapted constructor
    const type* const sentinel;
public:
    The_class() : sentinel(&reserved);
};
```